# htaccess permanent redirect - url with slug while address bar shows slug url

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, slug

From:

https://example.com/item.php?id=123

Desired (redirect to):

https://example.com/item123/slug

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^item([0-9]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ /item.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

above code works but only some of the time and I am stuck. The slug is NOT significant (disregarded and only for SEO) as I use the item number to figure out where to redirect to (also needs a permanent redirect 301).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean it works only some of the time? Can you be more specific? Are certain slugs causing it to break? Different layouts?

Comment: The slug does not appear in the address bar all the time... sometimes it actually shows the item.php?id=123 address

Comment: Your rule does not convert "old-format" to "new-format" automatically. For that, you'll need another rule

Comment: What kind of another rule? I am fairly new to rewrite rules, but researched it extensively... suggestions with examples greatly appreciated

Comment: slug can be anything - it is disregarded - only require the item number